# Error with awk (newline or end of string)

Tags: bash, awk

I am having an issue with the following command:

```
awk ‘{if ($1 ~ /^##contig/) {next}else if ($1 ~ /^#/) {print $0; next}else {print $0 | “sort -k1,1V -k2,2n”}’ file.vcf > out.vcf
```

It gives the following error:

```
^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command contains "fancy quotes" instead of normal ones, in addition to a missing `}`.

```
awk '{if ($1 ~ /^##contig/) {next} else if ($1 ~ /^#/) {print $0; next} else {print $0 | "sort -k1,1V -k2,2n"} }' file.vcf > out.vcf
```

Changing your command to the above should work as expected.